# Traverse forum threads using document.getElementById("treeForm") method

Tags: dom

I am traverse a forum's threads using DOM method. In the source code of the forum, I did not see any id = "treeForm", however, the document.getElementById("treeForm") returns the correct value. I don't know why that happens? If that ID is NOT exist in the forum's page source code, I think that it should return "null" instead. Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Is possible that element ID has been created dynamically.

Comment: If it is dynamically generated, is it suppose to be in the page source code? I did not find it in the page source code.

Comment: Maybe it is in a external javascript file